# Tensorflow returns same results for different trained input parameter

Tags: r, tensorflow, prediction

I want to implement a predict function with tensorflow in R, but the prediction result is always the same, no matter what the input parameters are.

I tried to stay really close to the official [tutorial](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorial_mnist_pros.html).

My training-data is shaped in a data.frame of 7 variables. The first one is the result. The result is either 0 or 1.

My full code is:

```
sess <- tf$InteractiveSession()

x <- tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL,6L))
y_ <- tf$placeholder(tf$float32, shape(NULL,2L))

W <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(shape(6L, 1L)))
b <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(shape(2L)))

sess$run(tf$global_variables_initializer())
y <- tf$nn$softmax(tf$matmul(x,W) + b)
cross_entropy <- tf$reduce_mean(-tf$reduce_sum(y_ * tf$log(y), reduction_indices=1L))
optimizer <- tf$train$GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train_step <- optimizer$minimize(cross_entropy)

i = 1
while (i < (nrow(training_data)-20)) {
    print(i)
    batch_ys <- matrix(c(training_data[i:(i+19),1], abs(training_data[i:(i+19),1]-1)), nrow=20)
    batch_xs <- matrix(c(training_data[i:(i+19),2],training_data[i:(i+19),3],training_data[i:(i+19),4],training_data[i:(i+19),5],training_data[i:(i+19),6],training_data[i:(i+19),7]), nrow=20, ncol=6)

    sess$run(train_step, feed_dict = dict(x = batch_xs, y_ = batch_ys))
    i = i + 20
}
```

And a simple check with the first items of the training data

```
# Simple verification
for (j in 1:30){
    test_data <- c(training_data[j,2],training_data[j,3],training_data[j,4],training_data[j,5],training_data[j,6],training_data[j,7])
    test_data <- matrix(test_data, nrow = 1, ncol = 6)
    feed_dict = dict(x= test_data)
    print('############')
    print(sess$run(y,feed_dict)) # this is always the same
    print(training_data[j,1])   
}
```

I expected that the prediction of depends on the input, but it returns:

```
[1] "############"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    2    2    4   74    5    2
      [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0657808 0.9342192
[1] 1
[1] "############"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    0    1    5   61    2    3
      [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0657808 0.9342192
[1] 0
[1] "############"
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    2    6   85    5    4
      [,1]      [,2]
[1,] 0.0657808 0.9342192
[1] 0
```

What did I do wrong?

Thanks,

Bastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out, why it doesn't work with the data.
The code worked really well, but the input-data wasn't scaled between 0 and 1.

I guess  all values over 1 were set to 1 (e.g. 32kg --> 1), so the nnet was trained only with tables filled with 1. Because of the same input-values for every output classification, the result was a constant value.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that problem is in this line:

```
W <- tf$Variable(tf$zeros(shape(6L, 1L)))
```

As you initialize weights matrix with zeros, all the gradients will be zeros as well. So, even after some training iterations `W` is still a matrix of zeros. The solution is to use small random values to initialize this matrix.

Comment: I tried to initialize W with `tf$random_normal` but the problem is still there.